# Suspiciously high accuracy in sentiment analysis model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am building a sentiment analysis model using `NLTK` and `scikitlearn`. I have decided to test a few different classifiers in order to see which is most accurate, and eventually use all of them as a means of producing a confidence score.

The datasets used for this testing were all reviews, labelled as either positive or negative.

I trained each classifier with 5,000 reviews, 5 separate times, with 6 different (but very similar) datasets. Each test was done with a new set of 5000 reviews.

I averaged the accuracy for each test and dataset, to arrive at an overall mean accuracy. Take a look:

- Multinomial Naive Bayes: **91.291%**
- Logistic Regression: **96.103%**
- SVC: **95.844%**

In some tests, the accuracy was as high as 99.912%. In fact, the lowest mean accuracy for one of the datasets was 81.524%.

Here's a relevant code snippet:

```
def get_features(comment, word_features):
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features[word] = (word in set(comment))
    return features

def main(dataset_name, column, limit): 
    data = get_data(column, limit)
    data = clean_data(data)  # filter stop words

    all_words = [w.lower() for (comment, category) in data for w in comment]
    word_features = nltk.FreqDist(all_words).keys()

    feature_set = [(get_features(comment, word_features), category) for
                       (comment, category) in data]

    run = 0
    while run < 5:
        random.shuffle(feature_set)

        training_set = feature_set[:int(len(data) / 2.)]
        testing_set = feature_set[int(len(data) / 2.):]

        classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC())
        classifier.train(training_set)

        acc = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set) * 100.
        save_acc(acc)  # function to save results as .csv

        run += 1
```

Although I know that these kinds of classifiers can typically return great results, this seems a little too good to be true.

**What are some things that I need to check to be sure this is valid?**

Comment: What is in `get_features` ? Have you cross-validated http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html ? Are there instances of train in test?

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Comment: BTW, depending on the ultimate application 96% might not be as good as you think. Imagine out of 100 people 4 people died. And then square that by a factor, out of 10,000 people 400 people died. Then square it again, out of 100,000,000 people, 400,000 people died because of your algorithm.

Comment: @alvas I have made sure that the testing data does not contain instances of the training data. After doing some checks, my biggest issue was that both the training and testing data were way too imbalanced! My `get_data` method was returning data that was 80% `pos` and 20% `neg`. I have fixed this now the accuracy is lower.

Comment: A stupid baseline would be to use 1 single label for all rows.

Comment: @alvas PS: I have added the `get_features` definition into my question for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so good if you get a range from 99,66% to 81,5%.

To analyze dataset in case of text classification, you can check:

- If the dataset is balanced?
- Distribution words for each label, sometimes the vocabulary used for each label can be really different.
- Positive/negative, but for the same source? Like the point before maybe if the domain is not the same, the reviews can use different expressions for a positive o negative review. This helps to get a high accuracy in several source.
- Try with a review from different source.

If after all you get that high accuracy, congrat! your get_features is really good. :)

Comment: Perhaps balancing is my issue. Should I make sure that my training data is 50% positive and 50% negative? Also I am unclear on what to check regarding your points 2) and 3)

Comment: 1) Yes, it's a recommendation that same number of samples for label.
2) separate dataset by positive/negative and individually performance like freqDist but with the words that your get_features doesn't clean, check if in the top n all are different.
3) like point 2 but for sources. If reviews are from twitter, amazon, facebook, etc. Are the same words use on each one for positive/negative=

Comment: Also consider other error metrics such as precision, recall and F-Score which can hint you towards problems. Also try a naive benchmark, such as always saying Positive (or Negative, depending on your larger class) and check their score against the ML models.

Comment: @MarcusV. Thanks, I will look into those.

Comment: @Tzomas I have added the definition of my `get_features` to the question. Why is it that you say that this function is the defining factor in getting high accuracy? It doesn't do anything special - surely it's the chosen classification algorithm that is of interest?

Comment: @Petar Ok your get_feature is simple. Beacuse for example you can clean stop words, those are words without meaning, like prepositions. Normalization of text like use lemmas or stems instead of all words, for time verbs for example.

If you made a good preprocessing for your text that get you to a better accuracy. The algorithm itself is not that important. Remember Data > Algorithm